# Workflow doesnt start anymore after add new item, how can I find the problem?

Tags: workflow, tasks

I am using sharepoint 2010 and created a visual studio workflow which is creating some tasks and assign it to some user or group. I have deploy for a couple of 3 times new versions to my environment. Before it was always working, but now not anymore. I have try to deploy an old wsp version, but it also not working. How can I debug or find the problem?

The workflow is created at my custom content type. I have a custom list which is using this custom content type. The workflow is triggered when an item is created or updated.

Comment: Is the item being created by a system account or a user account?

Comment: by a user account

Answer (score 0):

I would go back in your code in visual studios and either use a try/catch block to find and log the error or you can debug the workflow the following way:

In Visual Studios 2010:

- Deploy the newest version of the workflow.
- Go to to Debug -> Attach to Process -> Select `w3wp.exe` (usually the first one) -> Attach
- Fire the workflow manually
- Step through the code to see what causes the error and fix it.

Comment: how can I fire the workflow manually?

Comment: Navigate to the item, and use the drop-down menu -> "Workflows" -> then start the workflow from there, or you can select the item and on the top of the ribbon go to the Items/Document tab and click "Workflows"

Comment: but the workflow is set to the content type. Are you sure it is possible like you say? I see the workflow button, but I dont see something like start or run.

Comment: Make sure you are able to start it manually. Whenever you create a workflow you are given the option to allow the workflow to start manually, automatically from a change, and automatically from a new item.

Comment: I did enabled the "manuall start workflow" option, but I cannot again start the workflow manual. Someone told me to restart the sharepoint timer job service. Is this maybe the solution because the workflow timer job is stuck or someting?